Angular 18/algoliasearch 5 appID is missing only on production build using algoliasearch/lite
I have just upgraded algoliasearch in an Angular 18 app from version 4 to 5. Here are the pertinent imports:
import { ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_API_KEY, ALGOLIA_UNIT } from '@env';
import { liteClient, LiteClient } from 'algoliasearch/lite';

and client initialization:
this.searchClient = liteClient(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_API_KEY);

This works well when running this code in dev mode. However when running this in production mode I get appId is missing error. Most assuredly ALGOLIA_APP_ID is provided and is of type string in both cases.
Now if I replace algoliasearch/lite with algoliasearch as such:
import { algoliasearch, SearchClient } from 'algoliasearch';

this.searchClient = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_API_KEY);

this works in both dev and production builds.
The algoliasearch/lite node_module files are javascript and algoliasearch are typescript, and there appear to be no bugs in the code.
How can I get algoliasearch/lite working in production builds?
